# SAS: Data sets merge and print out full variable list but won't find variables for future use

Tags: sas, statistics

I successfully merged two datasets, as I can see when I use `proc contents` to print the new dataset, it has the correct number of variables and all of the variables that I am expecting are present. When I try to use the variables later on (like in `proc freq`/`proc univariate`) it says that the variables are not found. The variables are typed correctly as I copied and pasted them from the `proc contents`. There are no other errors on the log screen. The only issue I see is that about 15 commands in the total variable number is reduced from the full set to only one of the data sets, but there is no error or warning code.

Comment: What SAS Client are you using ? Can you update the question to show the `Proc CONTENTS` output ?

Answer (score 0):

Imported data can create data sets with column **names** that contain spaces.  Those names need to be specified 'later on' as name literals

Example:

```
var 'Miles Per Gallon'n 'Body Type'n 'Base Price'n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! It was easily solved by using the stop previous command button. Don't know why I didn't think of that sooner.